# I am getting a null pointer exception but I don't know why and the supposed saved drawing won't load

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am building an app that has multiple fragments and about half of those fragments contain a custom view that a user can draw lines with a finger (we'll call canvas), I am using a test app before I add new code to the main app. What I'm trying to do is to save the lines drawn by the user who then leaves the fragment for another one and draws some lines on the canvas in that fragment and can go back to the previous fragment (the drawing of the second will get saved) where the drawing for that fragment only will show in the canvas. If the user goes back to the second fragment, the drawing for the second fragment only will show, and also, the drawings should still be there when the app closes. I am using SharedPreferences.

When I go to one fragment (LineLHwFragment), I can draw on the canvas and click on save (I'll show where in the code) and it'll say "Data saved". If I close the app and load it again and go to that fragment, the drawing is not loaded.

Also, if I go to the other fragment (ChatFragment) either after clicking the first fragment or going to it first, the app crashes and I get this error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.ArrayList.iterator()' on a null object reference
    at com.josullivan.mytestapplication.PaintView.onDraw(PaintView.java:112)
```

I am not sure as to why it is not loading the drawing or why it crashes

**LineLHwFragment**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LineLHwFragment extends Fragment {

private PaintView paintView;
public ArrayList test;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_line_l_hw, container, false);
        paintView = v.findViewById(R.id.lineLPaintView);

        //This should get the drawing to load
        loadData();

       

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    paintView.init(metrics);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return v;

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.normal:
            paintView.normal();
            //this is where the saving should happen when clicked
            saveData();
            return true;

        case R.id.clear:
            paintView.clear();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void saveData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("line test 1", 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(paintView.getPaths());
    editor.putString("line test", json);
    editor.apply();
    Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void loadData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("line test 1", 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("line test", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<FingerPath>>() {}.getType();
   test = paintView.getPaths();
    test = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    paintView.setPaths(test);
}



}
```

**ChatFragment**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {

private PaintView paintView;
public ArrayList test;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);
        paintView = v.findViewById(R.id.paintView1);
        loadData();

       

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    paintView.init(metrics);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return v;

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.normal:
            paintView.normal();
            saveData();
            return true;

        case R.id.clear:
            paintView.clear();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void saveData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("chat test 1", 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(paintView.getPaths());
    editor.putString("chat test", json);
    editor.apply();
    Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void loadData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("chat test 1", 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("chat test", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<FingerPath>>() {}.getType();
    test = paintView.getPaths();
    test = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    paintView.setPaths(test);

}


}
```

**PaintView.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BlurMaskFilter;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.EmbossMaskFilter;
import android.graphics.MaskFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class PaintView extends View {

public static int BRUSH_SIZE = 10;
public static final int DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
public static int DEFAULT_BG_COLOR = Color.GRAY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
private float mX, mY;
private Path mPath;
private Paint mPaint;
private static ArrayList<FingerPath> paths = new ArrayList<>();
private int currentColor;
private int backgroundColor = DEFAULT_BG_COLOR;
private int strokeWidth;
private boolean emboss;
private boolean blur;
private MaskFilter mEmboss;
private MaskFilter mBlur;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Paint mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);



public PaintView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);

}

public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);

    mPaint.setColor(DEFAULT_COLOR);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setXfermode(null);
    mPaint.setAlpha(0xff);

    mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] {1, 1, 1}, 0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
    mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(5, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);

}

public ArrayList getPaths() {
    return paths;

}

public ArrayList setPaths(ArrayList<FingerPath> list) {

    return this.paths = list;
}

//public Path getMPath() {
    //return mPath;
// }

public void init(DisplayMetrics metrics) {
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;

    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

    currentColor = DEFAULT_COLOR;
    strokeWidth = BRUSH_SIZE;
}

public void normal() {
    emboss = false;
    blur = false;

}



public void clear() {
    backgroundColor = DEFAULT_BG_COLOR;
    paths.clear();
    normal();
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    mCanvas.drawColor(backgroundColor);


    //The null pointer exception points to this line
    for (FingerPath fp: paths) {
        mPaint.setColor(fp.color);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(fp.strokeWidth);
        mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);

        if (fp.emboss)
            mPaint.setMaskFilter(mEmboss);
        else if (fp.blur)
            mPaint.setMaskFilter(mBlur);

        mCanvas.drawPath(fp.path, mPaint);
    }

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

    canvas.restore();
}

private void touchStart(float x, float y) {
    mPath = new Path();
    FingerPath fp = new FingerPath(currentColor, emboss, blur, strokeWidth, mPath);
    paths.add(fp);

    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touchMove(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x-mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y-mY);

    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}

private void touchUp() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
            touchStart(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
            touchMove(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
            touchUp();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Point a debugger to the line `paintView.setPaths(test);` - is `test` null?

Comment: `test` should contain the ArrayList of details about the lines from the drawings. How would I put a debugger to the line `paintView.setPaths(test)`?

Comment: Depends on which debugger you have available. At a minimum, you could log the value of `test` right before that line.

Comment: I used log and got this: [  com.josullivan.mytestapplication.FingerPath@1dd71af, com.josullivan.mytestapplication.FingerPath@46e9bc, com.josullivan.mytestapplication.FingerPath@cd0fd45, com.josullivan.mytestapplication.FingerPath@a850c9a, com.josullivan.mytestapplication.FingerPath@d9979cb, com.josullivan.mytestapplication.FingerPath@b76e5a8, com.josullivan.mytestapplication.FingerPath@38928c1, com.josullivan.mytestapplication.FingerPath@2175866, com.josullivan.mytestapplication.FingerPath@5c3e7a7, com.josullivan.mytestapplication.FingerPath@728b454]